# Blackberry - how to get Application id?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mms

If am looking to get the Application ID for use in opening an mms connection

```
(MessageConnection) Connector.open("mms://[peer_address]:[application_Id]");
```

how do I get my application_Id?

I tried implementing a listener for incoming messages, however it is not able to detect incoming mms. I am suspecting it is due to wrong application id. (my [peer_address] is blank).

Any help would be appreciated